# A categorized (?) list of functional pearls in JFP and ICFP

Tags: reference-request, big-list, functional-programming

Is there a list of (categorized preferred) functional pearls ever published in ICFP and JFP? I could go to the ICFP proceedings and JFP issues and find all of them, but this would be time-consuming.

Haskell Wiki apparently has a list, but it only includes functional pearls that use Haskell as the language of presentation, and that excludes many beautiful functional pearls (e.g. the ICFP 2016 functional pearl on contracts).